# How to loop through pandas dataframe using a regular expression, counter, or string method and return a dictionary?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, methods

I have a pandas dataframe with common baby names listed on different rows. I need to loop through each name in each row and retrieve the number of times each letter of the alphabet appears as the last character of the baby name. I then need to return a dictionary of key and values where the keys are the 26 alphabet letters and the values are the frequency that the alphabet letters appear as the last character in all the baby names in the dataframe. [image: sample of pandas datafram]

Do I use a for loop with a regular expression? Do I use a counter? Do I use a string method after turning the column into a series?

With respect to a for loop and a regular expression, so far I have tried:

```
import re

for index, row in male_names.iterrows():
    male_last_letter_freq = row['name'](r'/(\w)\b/')
    male_letter_freq.update(male_last_letter_freq)

male_last_letter_freq
```

Clearly, I don't know the syntax for including the regular expression within the loop.

I have also tried to turn the 'name' column from the dataframe into a series and call some pandas .str methods:

```
male_name_series = male_names['name']
male_name_series.str.extract(r'/(\w)\b/')
```

Both ways return errors. I am really at a loss on how to do such a specific thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing is certain: do not use regex delimiters in Python patterns. Use `r'\w\b'` to match the last word char in "words".

Comment: string are lists of chars - the last one would be `name[:-1]`  ....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you don't need regular expressions, but just use:

```
dict(pd.value_counts(df["name"].str[-1]))
```

Explanation: `df["name"].str[-1]` extracts the last character, `pd.value_counts` counts unique value, finally `dict` converts the object to a dictionary

Comment: Thank you @user2314737. This worked. Now how would I create key and value headings for the letters and the frequencies so that I can plot the dictionary in a pandas data frame? Or is there a method I can just include in the code you already provided that will turn it into a data frame? I need the alphabet letters to be the x axis.

Comment: @Sören by using single square brackets for indexing one gets a series (see [indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics)) and `str` is a method of series.